# Xcode 7, simulator with black screen with apple logo

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode7

Ever since I upgraded to Xcode 7, I keep seeing this on my simulator every time I launch the simulator or I switch between the different simulators. Any reason why or how do I fix this? I've also made sure I don't have other apps running to use up my system resources.

Is this a hardware issue ? I'm using a '2.5 GHz Intel Core i5' MacBook Pro with 8GB RAM at home. At work I have a higher end retina display MacBook  Pro (2.7 GHz Intel Core i7) with 16GB RAM and I don't encounter any delays when loading the simulator or switching between them .

[image: Simulator image]

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing broken here, so there's nothing to fix.

The iOS 9 Simulator Runtime added the boot logo, so you will see it rather than a black screen on boot (just like on a real device).  Older runtimes just show a black screen.

The first time you boot a device (sim or real), it will display the progress bar as it runs through some initial setup steps.

Comment: Some text explaining that would be nice. For the first ~5 minutes the Apple logo and progress bar didn't even load and I was just looking at a black screen.

Comment: I'm not sure what additional text you want me to write.  Is there something not clear in my answer above?  If you're seeing 5 minutes pass before you see the logo and progress bar, then something is quite wrong.  You should file a bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com and include a sysdiagnose and your ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/[Device UDID].

Comment: I was talking about Apple. Some kind of text declaring that nothing was going wrong and that it was just loading painfully slow would help people like me.

Comment: That is exactly why we added the Apple Logo and progress bar UI, so developers now will see the progress instead of just a black screen.  On older runtimes, it was just black all the way until SpringBoard.  Seeing all black for 5 minutes before seeing the apple logo is NOT expected.  Please file a bug report with a sysdiagnose and your device's logs.

Comment: Some reeeeallllly sloooooow initial setup steps.

Comment: It should only take a few seconds, same as booting a physical device.  If you've got a spinning disk or are doing a bunch of disk I/O, it'll obviously take longer as it'll be bottlenecked by your other I/O.

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia All I can tell you is that launching the simulator from scratch in Xcode 8.1 takes foooorrrrreeeevvvvveeeeer. And this was _not_ true in previous versions of Xcode. My view is: it's only a simulator! Why can't it just _simulate_ starting up, i.e. imitate it but cut to the chase? My old outmoded real-life iPhone 4s starts up faster than your simulator.

Comment: iOS is a very rich environment.  There's no way to "cut to the chase" as you describe.  We need to boot the device.  Can you quantify "forever"?  Can you profile the startup and determine what is taking such a long time and why?  When I boot it up on my relatively dated 2011 MacMini with a HDD, it takes significantly less than a minute to boot the simulated  device (maybe ~30s).  With an SSD, it boots to the home screen in about 5s.

Comment: Also note that the issue in such cases is likely not the simulator itself but the runtime that is being booted.  You should compare booting iOS 8.1 with iOS 9.1 with iOS 10.1 booting in the same version of Simulator.app to determine if it really is an issue new to iOS 10.1 or something else going on.